# Problem with rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routing config:

```
resources :users do
  resources :apps, :controller => :user_apps
end
```

`rake routes` includes the following:

```
    user_apps GET    /users/:user_id/apps(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"user_apps"}
    user_apps POST   /users/:user_id/apps(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"user_apps"}
 new_user_app GET    /users/:user_id/apps/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"user_apps"}
edit_user_app GET    /users/:user_id/apps/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"user_apps"}
     user_app GET    /users/:user_id/apps/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_apps"}
     user_app PUT    /users/:user_id/apps/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"user_apps"}
     user_app DELETE /users/:user_id/apps/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"user_apps"}
```

However, when I try to access eg `user_apps_path(1,2)` I get `/users/1/apps.2` rather than `/users/1/apps/2`.

Where am I going wrong?

I'm using rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct route is `user_app_path(1,2)` The pluralized version goes to the `index` action, making the second argument the format / extension of the request.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm really embarrassed.